# How to instantiate this class without a default constructor?

Tags: c++

I have this class in C++

```
class vipWithAuth{
public:
string name, id;
float level;
vipWithAuth (string &n, string &i, float g) :
    name(n), id(i), level(g)
    {}
};
```

I tried many methods but I cannot come up with a way to instantiate this class. Can someone please help me?

Comment: you probably want const reference instead of non const ref.

Comment: @Jarod42, you should write an answer. I doubt OP understands the reasoning behind your comment.

Comment: Unless you tell the compiler not to, it will provide a default ctor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the constructor to use `const&` instead of a plain `&`,

```
vipWithAuth (string const& n, string const& i, float g) :
```

Then, you can construct an object of the class by using.

```
vipWithAuth obj("Name", "ID", 1.0f);
```

If you must keep the constructor the way it is, you'll have to use:

```
std::string name = "Name";
std::string ID = "ID";
vipWithAuth obj(name, ID, 1.0f);
```